# Ionic - Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, ionic3, gitignore

I just added the platforms and plugin files to the .gitignore and ran these commands

```
git rm -r --cached  .
git add .
git commit -m "message"
```

After successful pull and push, I was not able to run in the android device using the command

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I got the answer. I just Removed the android platform using the command

```
ionic cordova platform rm android
```

and then I added the android platform again using

```
ionic cordova platform add android
```